# Java Swing: Using ActionMap

Tags: java, swing, action, listener

I've seen a post earlier that recommends favoring Actions over listeners. I am not so familiar with the ActionMap. What are the disadvantages of the each approach? I like to make inner classes that implement listeners. Is that a bad practice?

Thanks

Comment: hmmm are we talking about http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html,

Comment: That is possible, though they only discuss key binding. Says there that key bindings result in easier to maintain code - this means an Action object is made with what I need inside, right? But can't I also put reusable code in the listener?

Comment: for beginer would be better to start with 1) plain Listener, if everything works then change rellated to the  2)  Action(s) http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html or 3) to the ActionMap, 4) for basic programing you doesn't see any differencies, code would be executed as you expect both ways, 5) but if you'll use Action/Map code should be more readable and maintanable 6) prepared for hight lever programing

Comment: Fair enough. It's a pretty good answer, but I can't rate it, probably because it's in a comment...

Comment: as you can see, sice good question and 5times up-voted, but without your code to really miss a question, everything was only on the academical level, and without better suggestions to concrete by answerers on this forum :-), I don't think that my comment(s) could be somehow good ..., there are better than me, :-) I still learning those ZOO about GUI as you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Key bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rely on [actions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). There is a potential risk that [`Action`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html) "implementations tend to be more expensive in terms of storage than a typical `ActionListener`." In practice, the problem does not arise. Here is an [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel).

Using [`KeyListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html) is conceptually easier to understand but typically more difficult to maintain. One inevitably ends up re-creating some kind of binding machinery. This [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/), while instructive and even appropriate for a game, is needlessly complex.

Comment: This is a good answer, but what do you mean about the storage? How are Actions more expensive than Listeners? I can see how maintenance is easier though.

Comment: The effect is implementation dependent, hinging critically on the effort required to implement the `Action`.

Comment: actually, there is no risk at all (all IMO, of course :-) The comment in api doc is historical - it was added at a time in Swing life when everybody was freaked out about performance and footprint, 10+ years ago. As to keyListeners: forget that they exist. They are at the same time cranky to handle and maintain _and_ too limited

Comment: @kleopatra's perspective is correct; it's not hard to make and application _seem_ sluggish with protracted actions, but the solution is to optimize the actions, not abandon key bindings.

Comment: So would you always use an Action over a listener? Or is there a certain case where listeners would be preferable?

Comment: @gsingh2011: As a practical matter, I'd consider `Action` whenever it's 1) used in more than one place, or 2) listed among the "Swing Components Supporting `Action`."