# Fetch data from database into Jtextfield when One Jtextfield is Typed

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, oracle11g

Hi Guys I have a Swing Application that is connected to an oracle database, I want it such that Once I type a Value into the JTextField, the other JTextfields on the JFrame are loaded with subsequent data from the database but I do not seem to achieve this. I have tried the Following code but it fetched nothing.

```
txtNo.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
            Connection conn = null;
            try{
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "Username", "Password");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String load = "Select * from Store_info_table where PART_NUMBER = '" + txtNo.getText() + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(load);
        while(rs.next()){
            txtName.setText(rs.getString("SPARE_DESC"));
        }
            }catch(Exception ae){

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried trimming the getText()?

Comment: Yes I have Nothing is coming on the txtName.

Comment: when you debug, does your ResultSet have results?

Comment: You might like to take a look at [Hw to write focus listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html), this will allow to monitor when the user leaves the field and act apon it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know if you're database connection is working?  For example, can you run the database portion outside of the listener and it works?

If so, I would suggest using `ActionListener`or a `FocusListener` instead.  KeyListeners (while sometimes necessary) are generally clumsy - there's usually a better approach (see [Java Swing: Using ActionMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253712/java-swing-using-actionmap) for and explaination):

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Example extends Box{

    JLabel txtName = new JLabel("Nothing Entered");

    public temp(){
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        // Add FocusListener to first field
        final JTextField txtNo = new JTextField(20);
        txtNo.addFocusListener(new CustomFocusListener(txtNo));
        add(txtNo);

        // Add TextListener to first field
        final JTextField txtNo2 = new JTextField(20);
        txtNo2.addFocusListener(new CustomFocusListener(txtNo2));
        add(txtNo2);

        // Add TextListener to first field
        final JTextField txtNo3 = new JTextField(20);
        txtNo3.addFocusListener(new CustomFocusListener(txtNo3));
        add(txtNo3);

        add(new JButton("Do Something"));

        add(txtName);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Example());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Your custom focust listener that does all your SQL Work
     */
    public class CustomFocusListener extends FocusAdapter{
        JTextField field;

        public CustomFocusListener(JTextField field){
            this.field = field;
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            //Assuming your database connection works, this gives you an example to follow
            txtName.setText(field.getText());
            /*Connection conn = null;
            try{
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "Username", "Password");
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String load = "Select * from Store_info_table where PART_NUMBER = '" + field.getText() + "'";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(load);
                while(rs.next()){
                   txtName.setText(rs.getString("SPARE_DESC"));
                }
            }catch(Exception ae){

            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Sure this Works if you are Pressing Enter But I have default Button on Enter and I still Have to Enter a Field or two in some JtextFields....How Can I get the same on Tab rather than Enter?

Comment: Ahh - I see.  You're really looking for a `FocusListener` then - something that will execute when the field loses focus.  I'll update my example for that.

Comment: @NickRippe No, you are looking for a `DocumentListener`

Comment: @Robin I suppose it depends on when you want to update your fields.  But I don't think you'd be able to easily catch a TAB character using the `DocumentListener` (because it's consumed by the `KeyboardFocusManager`).

Comment: Both a `DocumentListener` and `FocusListener` will work.  The problem with a `FocusListener` is the focus has to have some where to go.  If all the focusable components on the form are disabled (except the main one), focus will never be lost (I have this problem in a program at the moment). With a `DocumentListener` you will want some kind of delay between the document changes so that you don't try and load the data immediately it is changed...cause that would just be frustration. I do agree, however, get rid of the `KeyListener`

Answer (score 2):

- Replace the `KeyListener` by a `DocumentListener`
- The database connection on the EDT is a bad idea (too slow). Consult the [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) guide for more information
- You are vulnerable to SQL injection
- Avoid empty `catch` statements or you have no idea that something is going wrong. If you do not opt for decent error handling, at least log the stack trace (either by just printing it, or by using a `Logger`).

Answer (score 2):

Both Robin and Nick are right.

Here's an example of how to implement what they are discussing...

```
public class TestForm02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestForm02();
    }

    public TestForm02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new MyForm());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

    protected class MyForm extends JPanel {

        private JTextField txtNo;
        private JTextField txtName;
        private String partToLoad;
        private Timer loadTimer;

        public MyForm() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            txtName = new JTextField(12);
            txtNo = new JTextField(12);
            txtName.setEnabled(false);

            add(new JLabel("Parts #:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(txtNo, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            add(new JLabel("Description:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(txtName, gbc);

            txtNo.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                    loadParts();
                }
            });

            txtNo.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
                protected void update() {
                    loadTimer.restart();
                }

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    update();
                }
            });

            loadTimer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    loadParts();
                }
            });
            loadTimer.setRepeats(false);
            loadTimer.setCoalesce(true);

        }

        protected void loadParts() {

            String text = txtNo.getText();
            // Don't want to trigger this twice...
            if (text == null ? partToLoad != null : !text.equals(partToLoad)) {
                partToLoad = text;
                txtNo.setEnabled(false);
                txtName.setEnabled(false);
                BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                worker.execute();
            }

        }

        protected class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {

                // Do you're database load here.  Rather then updating the text
                // field, assign it to variable and return it from here

                String desc = "Some description"; // load me :D

                // Inserted delay for simulation...
                Thread.sleep(2000);

                return desc;

            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    String value = get();
                    txtName.setText(value);

                    txtName.setEnabled(true);
                    txtNo.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace(); // Log these some where useful
                } catch (ExecutionException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace(); // Log these some where useful
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the Help. I got what I wanted Using a FocusListener as suggested by Nick:

```
 txtNo.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            Connection conn = null;
            try{
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "Username", "Password");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String load = "Select * from Store_info_table where PART_NUMBER = '" + txtNo.getText().trim() + "'";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(load);
        while(rs.next()){
            txtName.setText(rs.getString("SPARE_DESC"));

        }
            }catch(Exception ae){

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: A number of things concern me here. You're still calling the database from within the EDT, which will block your UI & potentially make your program look as if its hung. Establishing a connection in this manner is wasteful and time consuming. You're not closing the connection or resultset, consuming database resources. You're not treating the exception, how are you going to track errors if you, at least, never report them and are you expecting more then one row to be returned for any given part number? Cause your only every displaying the last result