# Editable JComboBox KeyPressed not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this code where I designed an `editable JComboBox` to listen to my `keyPressed` event and show a message that the key is pressed. But I have no idea why this not working. *As a beginner I might have gone wrong logically/conceptually.*

So, I would request for suggestions about how to construct the code, so that it works.

**Code**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class testEJCBX extends JFrame {
    JComboBox jcbx = new JComboBox();

    public testEJCBX() {
        super("Editable JComboBox");
        jcbx.setEditable(true);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(jcbx);

        jcbx.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
            {
                jcbxKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        setSize(300, 170);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private void jcbxKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Key Pressed");
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new testEJCBX();
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyListener` is a poor choice generally, but in your case, the `KeyEvent`s aren't been sent to the `JComboBox`, but to the component which is acting as the editor of the `JComboBox`.  What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to get a message when any key is pressed inside the `Editable JComboBox`

Comment: How can it be done? or more precisely how should I achieve the same?

Comment: *"I am just trying to get a message when any key is pressed inside the Editable JComboBox"* - Why? My point is, you can use a `FocusListener` to know when the component/editor becomes focused for example, you "should" use a `DocumentListener` when you want to know when the field is changed, but there might be issues with this, you should use a `DocumentFilter` if you want to filter what gets entered into the field.  Which one would be right for you is impossible to know until we understand what is you're hoping to achieve

Comment: @MadProgrammer . What would be the optimum java component to use if I want to dynamically get results from a DB when I press a key. That key would be passed to the query offcourse. Eg : `SELECT * from ..... where val='*jcbxValue*`';

Comment: I would "suggest" a `DocumentListener`, mixed with a Swing `Timer` and a `SwingWorker`, you don't want to be running off to the database on each key stroke, you need to allow the user to stop typing, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751706/fetch-data-from-database-into-jtextfield-when-one-jtextfield-is-typed/12754738#12754738)

Comment: Yes for that purpose I dont want to reinvent the wheel though :). I thought of using a SwingX `AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(jcbx)` .

Comment: @MadProgrammer : I have planned to open the connection beforehand and then quering the DB when the user types in. But I am really confused about how to construct all these at one place

Comment: SwingX's AutoComplete may not be suitable since you're pulling results from the database, which will require time, which could "freeze" the UI if you don't off load the loading to the background

Comment: Should I dynamically store the results from `ResultSet` to a `List` and then populate the dropdown?

Comment: I don't have any issue the combobox, but you're probably going to have to do some of your own work to get it to work the way you want

Comment: I already got a fair idea about what should I do @MadProgrammer, and many thanks for that. But as you were mentioning *"SwingX's AutoComplete may not be suitable.......database"* I asked you what would be the proper way to do it and in-context to that I do not understand the reason of a **Down Vote**

Comment: Not the downvoter so I can't speak for it.  The problem is, context is a little light on the ground.  Personally, I might, for example, use `JTextField` and a `JList` wrapped in a `JDialog` to act as a "look up" mechanism, using the example idea I presented eailer

Comment: Oh!! Thanks for that again. Will follow your advice :). But I do not understand people who do good work for SO and gain *Reputation >125* and without studying the context of the program *downvote* some questions. I also mentioned that ***As a beginner I might have gone wrong logically/conceptually***. I would be very much happy indeed **if any downvote in SO is done with a mention of the reason.**

Comment: Stick around a week, you'll see something like this asked about 2-3 times, not always exact, but close to it. Also, we were missing the context of your problem "I have this code, it's not working" doesn't really help us help you, just saying ;) - Oh, and if I do downvote, you will know it was me ;), because I will have spent sometime to encourage you to improve your question/answer before I resort to it ;)

Comment: Will edit the code as needed @MadProgrammer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a KeyListener for this sort of thing. Rather if you want to detect changes to the combo box's editor component, extract it and add a DocumentListener to it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestEJCBX extends JFrame {
   JComboBox<String> jcbx = new JComboBox<>();

   public TestEJCBX() {
      super("Editable JComboBox");
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      jcbx.setEditable(true);

      getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
      getContentPane().add(jcbx);

      JTextField editorComponent = (JTextField) jcbx.getEditor()
            .getEditorComponent();

      Document doc = editorComponent.getDocument();
      doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("text changed");
         }

         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("text changed");
         }

         @Override
         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("text changed");
         }
      });

      pack();
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String argv[]) {
      new TestEJCBX();
   }
}
```

Comment: While this is correct and I have no issue with it, if the OP tries to modify the field in some way, it will cause a mutation exception.  I "suspect" that they are trying to create a auto complete field, but I have no idea :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: true of course. I was going on the assumption that he was looking just for notification and not mutation. To mutate, he could use a DocumentFilter, or else he could cheat, use a DocumentListener, place the mutation code in a Runnable and queue it onto the event thread.

Comment: As I say, I have no evidence one way or the other :P

Comment: I did not know about working with a `Document` component. Really appreciate that. VotedUp