# How to set jtextfield from database when the other jtextfield is typed?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtextfield, sqlexception

Sorry before, I know this question has already been asked and has the solution. But when I try to do the same thing, it doesn't work. I have try the solution from the solved question but doesn't work on mine. I used FocusLost event on my jtextfield, when the focus is lost, it shows the exception messages. please help, thank you.

I'm trying to do exactly the same as this [solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751706/fetch-data-from-database-into-jtextfield-when-one-jtextfield-is-typed).

here's my FocusLost event as suggested on the link above, and the code is nearly the same.

```
     private void kdbarangTxtFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                      
        try{
        java.sql.Connection conn = new Koneksi().konek();

        String sql = "select nama_brg from barang where kode_brg = '"+kdbarangTxt.getText().trim()+"'";

        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet rslt = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rslt.next()){
            nmbarangTxt.setText(rslt.getString("kode_brg"));
        }rslt.close();
        conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not found");
        }
     }
```

**EDIT**

I used stacktrace, and here's the result
`java.sql.SQLException: Column 'kode_brg' not found.`

here's the screenshot, that column does exist ->
[My database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKSYc.png)

Comment: 1) *"it shows the exception messages"* So.. what are they? Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 4) BTW - the IDE has nothing to do with this, so don't add the tag.

Comment: I mean it shows catch error which is in my code "Item not found". So sorry, I'm really new in stackoverflow :(

Comment: Change `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not found");` to something **useful** like `e.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item not found");`

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why your getting an error, but ignoring the exception isn't going to help you (or us).  You should be using a `PreparedStatement` and you should be managing your resources better (closing the connection, statement and result set)

Comment: could you please show some sample records? have you tried checking if the `resulset` is `null` or `0`? it could be because your query returns `0` rows and I think that it is because you are trimming the value from your `textBox`. please edit add add more info like your `stacktrace` or sample record.

Comment: for the stacktrace result is `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'kode_brg' not found.`. why does my database column not found?

Comment: *"why does my database column not found?"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @NaufalBayu Does the column exist in the specified table?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes it does exist. I'll provide you the screenhshot of my table.

Comment: You get `nama_brg` column from select statement but trying to set `rslt.getString("kode_brg")` thats why you get exception.

Answer (score 0):

it's solved now as suggested from @newuserua_ext

My mistake was in `rslt.getString("kode_brg")`, it should `rslt.getString("nama_brg")` nama_brg is the column I'm trying to show in my jTextField.

Thank you to all of you who has answered my question. Cheers!